# Removing the last character of a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that receives 2 parameters I would like to take the last character of one of these parameters does anyone know how to do, using mysql?

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_status`(IN status_p CHAR(1), IN codigo_p VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
UPDATE cartaodigital SET statusPedido = status_p WHERE id_cartaodigital = codigo_p;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
select substring(COLUMNNAME from length(COLUMNNAME))
from TABLENAME;
```

or

```
select substring(COLUMNNAME, length(COLUMNNAME))
from TABLENAME;
```

or

```
select substring(COLUMNNAME from -1)
from TABLENAME;
```

or

```
select substring(COLUMNNAME, -1)
from TABLENAME;
```

Comment: Thank you, I came to this SUBSTRING (codigo_p FROM 1 FOR LENGTH (codigo_p) -1)

Comment: @JerfesonGuerreiro That is the same thing as `SUBSTRING(codigo_p FROM -1)`